# Find and Highlight Cell Containing Text IF Adjacent Cell Contains Specific Text

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a Sub where the cell containing the number 0 is highlighted IF the adjacent cell contains the word "SAMPLE." I haven't been able to find any code to model mine after, so links would be much appreciated! Here is an example of the cell layout: I manually highlighted the target cells in blue to point them out.

[image: []

Here is my code:

```
'PURPOSE: Find SAMPLES that contain zero N/Mol and highlight the cell yellow
Sub Find_Highlight_ZeroNitrogenSAMPLE()
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim Match As Range
Dim FirstAddress As Variant

Set WS = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Report Sheet 1")
Set Match = WS.Cells.Find(What:="0", LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False)
    'Find cells containing zero

    If Not Match Is Nothing And Match.Offset(, 3) = "SAMPLE" Then
    'Highlight If cell three columns over is SAMPLE
    FirstAddress = Match.Address
        Do
        Match.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        'Highlight cell containing zero
        Set Match = WS.Cells.FindNext(Match)
        Loop While Not Match Is Nothing And Match.Address <> FirstAddress
    End If
End Sub
```

I'm not sure if I'm completely b*stardizing this, any hints?

Comment: Why not use Conditional Formatting?

Comment: `Applies to: T:T,W:W` using the formula `=AND($T1=0,$W1="SAMPLE")`

Comment: @ScottCraner Hey again Scott, thanks for helping me out again. Where would I insert "Applies to:" in my code? Or is it not inserted in VBA? I'm very new to conditional formatting.

Comment: That is for conditional formatting rules, no vba needed.

Comment: @ScottCraner Ah, gotcha. Ideally, I'd like to embed the function in a VBA module. Is it not possible to achieve this in VBA?

Comment: it is definitely possible in vba.  I was just suggesting a method without vba.  I will keep quiet and let the vba experts help.

Comment: You can apply CF with VBA. What exactly is wrong with your current code?

Comment: I think your loop should just check if 0 is found and the check for column W should be inside your loop. i.e. you find every instance of 0 and check each time W.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with Scott that CF is the way to go, but here is an adaptation of your `Find` approach.

You can also check at the beginning if there are any rows satisfying both criteria.

```
Sub Find_Highlight_ZeroNitrogenSAMPLE()

Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim Match As Range
Dim FirstAddress As String 'not variant

Set WS = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Report Sheet 1")

'first check there are any cases before proceeding
If WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(WS.Range("T:T"), 0, WS.Range("W:W"), "SAMPLE") = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No instances of 0 and SAMPLE"
    Exit Sub
End If

Set Match = WS.Cells.Find(What:="0", LookIn:=xlValues, _
                          LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                          MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False) 'probably don't need quotes around "0"

'Find cells containing zero
If Not Match Is Nothing Then
    FirstAddress = Match.Address
    Do
        If Match.Offset(, 3).Value = "SAMPLE" Then
            Match.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
            'Highlight cell containing zero
        End If
        Set Match = WS.Cells.FindNext(Match)
    Loop While Match.Address <> FirstAddress 'stop as soon as back to first case, Match will never be Nothing
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you! I have two follow-up questions: 1) Can you elaborate as to why you'd use CF in this case? And 2) Can you also elaborate on the last comment in your code regarding the loop? Are you saying that this function will continually loop without ending because I didn't specify a condition under which it should stop?

Comment: (1) Generally better to use Excel's built-in functionality where possible, although `Find` is much better than a straightforward loop through every row.

Comment: (2) Not really. In this line `Loop While Not Match Is Nothing And Match.Address <> FirstAddress` the first bit is redundant as if `Match` were `Nothing` that would mean 0 was never found and you would never have entered the `Do` loop in the first place. Also if `Match` were `Nothing` trying to access its `Address` property would result in an error.  I believe this error arises from MS's own help.

Comment: That all makes sense. Thank you again!!